# Subdomain to IPs based on Port

Tags: dns, ip, cloudflare, portforwarding, nat

Is there any Solution via DNS (Cloudflare) to redirect the same subdomain to different IPs based on Port requested? Like:

`one.example.com on Port 80 -> 1.1.1.1`

`one.example.com on Port 443 -> 1.1.1.1`

`one.example.com on Port 23455 -> 2.2.2.2`

Or to redirect all Ports to a IP except one/two Ports to another? Like:

`one.example.com -> 1.1.1.1` but

`one.example.com on Port 80 -> 2.2.2.2`

`one.example.com on Port 443 -> 2.2.2.2`

The Traffic to 2.2.2.2 on Port 23455 should not go over 1.1.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS A-record resolution (name to IP address) can't be made depending on TCP port numbers. DNS name identify a host, not a service.

What you're looking for can be done with a destination NAT (DNAT) router though. The DNS name resolves to the public IP of the NAT router and the router forwards the connections depending on port numbers to different hosts behind the router.

Comment: But then all the traffic goes through first server right?

Comment: With a DNAT router, all traffic will go through the router first. The router uses the port number to decide where to forward a request (and traffic) to.